# Terraform for azure autoupgrade: string required

Tags: azure, terraform, terragrunt

I am trying to add terraform for azure automatic upgrade channel. when I try with automatic_channel_upgrade = "patch" with string It is working fine. But when i want to use multiple attributes like automatic_channel_upgrade = ["patch","node-image"] with list I am having Inappropriate value for attribute "automatic_channel_upgrade": string required. Is there any way to issue multiple parameters.

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "private_aks" {
  name                       = var.private_aks_name
  automatic_channel_upgrade = var.automatic_channel_upgrade
```

}

```
variable "automatic_channel_upgrade" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["patch","node-image"]
}
```

Comment: The argument expects you to provide only a single string, so the answer is no.

Comment: Having checked `autoupgrade` documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/auto-upgrade-cluster). `list` is not accepted, it got to be a string & that's what `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` expects which is inline. 
Not sure what's your intention of using a list here which is against the API as well provider.